# How to get value of Html.DropDownList in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I have assigned the following viewbag in the controller

```
public ActionResult new_vehicle()
    {
        ViewBag.customers = new SelectList(db.customers, "cust_id", "cust_name");
        return View(db.vehicles.ToList());
    }
```

and the code in view is

```
 @Html.DropDownList("customers", "Select Customer");
```

the code for add function is

```
public ActionResult veh_AddEdit()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request["vehiddenID"]);
        if (id == 0)
        {

            vehicle veh = new vehicle();
            Session["veh_id"] = "";

            veh.cust_id_fk = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["customers"]);
            veh.veh_make = Request["vemake"];
            veh.veh_name = Request["vename"];
            veh.veh_model = Request["vemodel"];
            db.vehicles.Add(veh);
            db.SaveChanges();
            int latestEmpId = veh.veh_id;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("new_vehicle");
    }
```

The problem is that its not getting the selected value i.e foreign key in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you can pass in viewbag `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

```
public ActionResult new_vehicle()
{
    ViewBag.customers = db.customers.Select(i=>new SelectListItem() { Text = i.cust_name, Value=i.cust_id });
    return View(db.vehicles.ToList());
}
```

Then in your view you can render dropdown like that

```
@Html.DropDownList("customers", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.customers, "Select Customer")
```

And then in your controller in your method `veh_AddEdit` you can access it like `Request["customers"]`

Comment: If it's working for you, can you please accept my answer

Comment: I'm new here so did not know.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you got the solution from victor's answer, here i would like to provide additional info, by hoping that it will helps to understand better

In general Html form, will send the values to the controller ,using the key-value pair. so for the dropdownlist name will be the key and value will be the ,which the user is selected.

To check that once html is rendered for the dropdownlist ,just go to the view page source in browser and get the name of the control to use it in the action method.

Ex:

```
public ActionResult veh_AddEdit(string customers)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request["vehiddenID"]);
        if (id == 0)
        {

            vehicle veh = new vehicle();
            Session["veh_id"] = "";

            veh.cust_id_fk = Convert.ToInt32(customers);
            veh.veh_make = Request["vemake"];
            veh.veh_name = Request["vename"];
            veh.veh_model = Request["vemodel"];
            db.vehicles.Add(veh);
            db.SaveChanges();
            int latestEmpId = veh.veh_id;
        }

        return RedirectToAction("new_vehicle");
    }
```